# How do I put a ESXi host into maintenance mode using pyvmomi?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I was asked to write some python code that would put an VMWare ESXi host into maintenance mode.  I was given the name of a virtual center, `test-vc`, and the hostname of an ESXi host, `test-esxi-host` and this link ...

https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/HostSystem.rst

... which provides some documentation on the method I am suppose to use, `EnterMaintenanceMode(timeout, evacuatePoweredOffVms, maintenanceSpec)`.

I am really a complete loss as to what to do really and could use some help.  I have tried doing this from a python console:

```
from pyVmomi import vim
vim.HostSystem.EnterMaintenanceMode(timeout=0)
```

Which results in this error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/apps/cpm/red/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVmomi/VmomiSupport.py", line 574, in __call__
    return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _InvokeMethod() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Also I am a kind of confused about how the `EnterMaintenanaceMode` routine would know that I want to put the host `test-esxi-host` in virtual center `test-vc`?

Update: I think I have figured it out. Here's what I think I need to do:

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import atexit

si = SmartConnectNoSSL(host=vc_host, user=user, pwd=pwd)
cont = si.RetrieveContent()
atexit.register(Disconnect, si) # maybe. I am not really sure what this does
objview = si.content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(si.content.rootFolder, [vim.HostSystem], True)
objview.view[0].EnterMaintenanceMode(0)
```

Of course the line

```
objview.view[0].EnterMaintenanceMode(0)
```

is sure to wreak havoc as I have no idea if that is the host, 'test-esxi-host', I want to put into maintenance mode.  I guess I could do this

```
for h in objview.view:
   if h.name == 'test-esxi-host'
      h.EnterMaintenanceMode(0)
```

I hope there is a better way to do the above. Something like

```
get_host(objview.view, 'test-esxi-host').EnterMaintenanceMode(0)
```

Comment: Seems to me as a Host method. It should expect you to define your host first (HostSystem class) and then run that method in your instance.

Comment: Thanks @Cheche I'll try to figure out how to do that. Have you worked with this vmware PyVmomi before?  I cannot find any good documentation on it.

Comment: Yes I worked mainly with VMs. I'll have a look tomorrow to see if I can help you. Sorry but I don't have access to the code right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Getting started with VMwares ESXi/vSphere API in Python](https://www.jacobtomlinson.co.uk/vmware/2016/06/22/using-vmware-esxi-vsphere-python-api/).

> To get a VM object or a list of objects you can use the [searchIndex](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/SearchIndex.rst)
>   class. The class had methods to search for VMs by UUID, DNS name, IP
>   address or datastore path.

Hopefuly, there are a couple of ways to look for objects in vCenter:

- FindByUuid (VM|Host)
- FindByDatastorePath (VM)
- FindByDnsName (VM|Host)
- FindByIp (VM|Host)
- FindByInventoryPath (managed entity: VM|Host|Resource Pools|..)
- FindChild (managed entity)

Many of these also have `FindAll..` methods which allow a much broader look up.

For this particular case, you could use `FindByDnsName` to look for your host.

```
searcher = si.content.searchIndex
host = searcher.FindByDnsName(dnsName='test-esxi-host', vmSearch=False)
host.EnterMaintenanceMode(0)
```

This code requires you to authenticate to vCenter (@`SmartConnectNoSSL`) with a user having `Host.Config.Maintenance` privileges.

Finally you can take your host out of maintenance mode with: `host.ExitMaintenanceMode(0)`